# Google Oauth 2.0 - redirect_uri mismatch despite being identical to an authorized redirect uri in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have seen this issue being addressed in many other posts but none of them has solved my problem. I have a front-end Vue.js application and a spring boot Java application.

I am using the vue-google-oauth to prompt the Google sign in from my front end application to get the auth code, then I wanted to use my backend server to get user details and handle logic there.

On Google Cloud Platform I defined an Authorized redirect URI:

[image: Authorized redirect URI]

and I am using this very same uri when I am sending my auth code in the front end

```js
import api from "@/assets/js/api";
import AdminNavigation from "./AdminNavigation";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import Axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["IsSignedIn"]),
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Christopher s' portfolio admin",
      appDescription:
        "Here you can add contents for the front end portfolio website.",
      isInit: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    AdminNavigation,
  },
  methods: {
    signIn: async function () {
      try {
        const authCode = await this.$gAuth.getAuthCode();
        Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/authenticate", {
          code: authCode,
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard",
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    let that = this;
    let checkGauthLoad = setInterval(function () {
      that.isInit = that.$gAuth.isInit;
      if (!this.IsSignedIn) {
        that.signIn();
      }

      if (that.isInit) clearInterval(checkGauthLoad);
    }, 1000);
  },
};
```

My backend server receives the auth code and the redirect_uri which is identical to what was defined on Google Cloud Platform.

```java
package com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.controllers;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.general.ConstantVariables;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import static org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@Controller
public class AdminController {
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String authentication(HttpEntity<String> data) throws IOException, ParseException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data.getBody());

        String authCode = json.get("code").toString();
        String redirect_uri = json.get("redirect_uri").toString();

        try {
            GoogleTokenResponse response =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                    ConstantVariables.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                    ConstantVariables.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    authCode, redirect_uri).execute();

            System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());


        } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
            if (e.getDetails() != null) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getDetails().getError());
                if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
                    System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorDescription());
                }
                if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
                    System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorUri());
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
 400 Bad Request redirect_uri_mismatch
```

I kept looking at a lot of stack overflow questions and no solution worked for me so far... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not sending the OAuth details you think you are. Have you captured HTTPS messages to the Authorization Server from your Spring Boot back end - and can you post details here?

If it helps, [this blog post of mine](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/http-debugging-setup/) includes some notes on configuring an HTTP proxy in Java.